# Music stops when the screen is off

Tags: lock-screens, background-process, android-10

After selecting a music file to open in file explorer in a floating mode, the music stops as soon as the phone is locked. I whitelisted both the player and explorer in battery saver settings but no luck. Playing music in the music player itself isn't creating this problem, though.

[image]

(Click to enlarge)

Edit: The device is Redmi 5 plus but it's on a custom rom (Havoc OS 3.3, Android Q). The music player is [Hash Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hashmusic.musicplayer)

Comment: Could you reclarify on "playing music in the music player itself isn't creating this problem"? Did you mean the issue only occurs when playing music from file explorer, but not if directly from the player? Also, each music player has different behavior, so more details (as asked above) will help us more in finding the solution.

Comment: @AndrewT. I wanted to say that playing songs directly from the player doesn't create this problem. But when I open an audio file from explorer with a floating screen (see the screenshot above), the (floating) player stops working when the phone gets locked. I added more information in the edit above.

Comment: I don't think screen off/on has any bearing on this app. I installed the app, played the music from stock file manager. But the moment I switched to an another app music stopped. It is likely the app is not creating a background service (I didn't verify though) to continue the playback when its activity (that floating window) is destroyed.